# Видео слайдер в модальном окне при закрытии модального окна звук от видео остается

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ребят , есть видео слайдер карусель, с 4-мя миниатюрами. Проблема в том, что при закрытии модального окна звук с видео остается. Как исправить, на чисто js?

```css
/* Базовые стили слоя затемнения и модального окна  */

.overlay {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
  /* фон затемнения */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  position: fixed;
  /* фиксированное поцизионирование */
  cursor: default;
  /* тип курсара */
}


/* активируем слой затемнения */

.overlay:target {
  display: block;
}


/* стили модального окна */

.popup {
  right: 0;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 14px;
  z-index: 20;
  width: 1030px;
  height: 640px;
  margin-top: -75px;
  /* фиксированное позиционирование, окно стабильно при прокрутке */
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid #383838;
  background: #fefefe;
  /* внешняя тень */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .22), 0 19px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .22), 0 19px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-out;
}


/* активируем модальный блок */

.overlay:target+.popup {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  top: 20%;
}


/* формируем кнопку закрытия */

.close {
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 13px/20px 'Tahoma', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-transition: all ease .8s;
  transition: all ease .8s;
}

.close:before {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  content: "X";
  text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  font-size: 12px;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: rgba(252, 20, 0, 0.8);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}


/* изображения внутри окна */

.popup img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}


/* элементы м-медиа, фреймы */

.popup embed,
.popup iframe {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.popup h2 {
  /* заголовок 2 */
  margin: 0;
  color: #008000;
  padding: 5px 0px 10px;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #adadad;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-family: 'Tahoma', Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.3;
}


/* параграфы */

.popup p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0
}


/*content*/

.content {
  width: 1030px;
  height: 640px;
  background: url("images/main-bg.jpg") no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<a href="#win1" class="button-image"><img src="images/banner.png"></a>
<a href="#x" class="overlay" id="win1"></a>
<div class="popup">
  <div class="content">
    <div id="slider">
      <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide1" checked="">
      <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide2">
      <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide3">
      <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide4">

      <div id="slides">
        <div id="overflow">
          <div class="inner">
            <div class="page">
              <video src="videos/1.mp4" class="vidos" preload="metadata" autoplay controls></video>
            </div>
            <div class="page">
              <img src="images/4.gif" />
            </div>
            <div class="page">
              <video src="videos/3.mp4" class="vidos" preload="metadata" controls></video>
            </div>
            <div class="page">
              <video src="videos/1.mp4" class="vidos" preload="metadata" controls></video>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--inner-->
        </div>
        <!--overflow-->
      </div>
      <!--slides-->

      <div id="active">
        <label for="slide1">
         <video src="videos/1.mp4"></video>
        </label>
        <label for="slide2">
         <img src="images/2.jpg"/>
        </label>
        <label for="slide3">
         <video src="videos/3.mp4"></video>
        </label>
        <label for="slide4">
         <video src="videos/1.mp4"></video>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="close" title="Закрыть" href="#close"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: где именно ? что то не получилось

Comment: @Air обновил код

Comment: @Air этот модальное окно полностью на CSS

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64226/discussion-between-anton-and-air).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, вот так:

```
var videos = document.querySelectorAll('#slides video');
var closeBtn = document.getElementById('win1');

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(videos, function(el, i) {
    el.pause();
    el.currentTime = 0;
  });
});
```